# How can I get the debian weak keys black list

Tags: linux, debian

Is there a list for RSA black listed debian weak keys? I tried to search, but all what I can find is some tools for checking. What if I want the list itself? Is this available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in packages [openssl-blacklist](http://packages.debian.org/source/squeeze/openssl-blacklist) and  [openssh-blacklist](http://packages.debian.org/source/squeeze/openssh-blacklist).

Comment: Can I get it in txt format?

Comment: The packages contain text files with partial fingerprints of all affected keys.

Comment: Is there any way where I can get they keys in hex. format (or even decimal but not a partial fingerprints) ? I have couple of certs that I want to check. I want to be sure by seeing the key in the blacklist and compare it to the one in the cert.

Comment: The openssh-blacklist source package contains a tool that generates all affected ssh keys.

Comment: But this seems only possible for openssh-blacklist NOT for openssl-blacklist which I need. See: http://wiki.debian.org/SSLkeys